# changes command only display current file change history

Tags: navigation

The `:changes` command listed the change history of current file. However when I work with multiple buffers, I want to list changes to all the buffers I opened in current vim-server, like the behavior of `tags` and `jumplist`. Is there such facility available?

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but [this snippet](https://0x0.st/sUIj.txt) should install a mapping triggered by the keys `g:c`. When you press it, it should populate the quickfix list with the changelists of all the existing buffers. It requires at least the patch [8.0.1514](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1514), for the `getchangelist()` function to be available.

Comment: @user938271, this is really near what I want. It is better to have some adjustment. For example, only shows the file name instead of the full path, shows the current line content after the change location.
It is more usable if the list can be sorted using timestamp instead of being sorted by buffer. But I guess currently vim don't provide the facility to add a timestamp for each change.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you're looking for a combined change list; unlike `:jumps`, changes are not global, but local to each buffer.

What you can do is iterate over all open buffers:

```
:bufdo changes
```

Comment: This command can only show the changes, but don't provide navigation command like `g,` and `g;`. Wondering if there is some plugin that can jump between all these changes

Comment: I don't think so, because obtaining all changes via `:changes` is costly, and then would require parsing and merging, which is not easy to implement.